# Function is triggered unexpectedly - nodeJS

Tags: node.js, typescript

I have two entry points in my project updated.ts & test.ts,
In update.ts there is a self invoked function like this

```
let main = ()=>{// do something}
main()
```

but when I run in my terminal `node test.ts` main() is also triggered,
Is this a compiler thing? how can I work around it? I do import other functions from update.ts
**expected behaviour:**  run `node test.ts` and import other functions from updated.ts without `main()` being triggered

Comment: You can't import a file without running that file's code. Extract the common functionality to a third file.

Comment: When you import a file, the code has to be run in order for the variables, functions, and other stuff inside the module to be defined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you load a module, anything in the body of the module — including the defining of variables and evaluation of `main()` — will run.

It's necessary. Consider:

```
let initialized = null;

const main = () => {
    initialized = new Date();
} 

main();

export const other = () => {
    return initialized;
}
```

… you might only be importing `other` but its functionality depends on the side effects of the rest of the code in the module running.

If you don't want to call `main()` every time the module is loaded, then don't put `main()` in the body of that module.

You might want to split `main` and the other code in the module into separate modules.